# Using jQuery .load function when images are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I'm wanting to use the jQuery `.load` function to run some code when all the images are loaded on the page.

```
jQuery("img").load(function () {
    //run some code
});
```

Now the code runs but my question is, will the code run after all images on the page are loaded or will the code run when the first image element is loaded.

I know I can use the jQuery `$(document).ready` function or the `$(window).load function, but this will fire when everything is loaded.
I want the code to run when the image elements are loaded, and before all the scripts in the footer load.

Anyone care to share their expert opinion on the matter?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use the load function with the window instead of img's:

```js
$(window).on('load', function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded 
  console.log("Everything loaded");
})
```

EDIT: Here you have a working example of a preloader:
https://codepen.io/niklausgerber/pen/MKrVdQ

Comment: Hi Manuel, thanks for the help. This is not what I was asking, I have edited my question. I wan't to know if I have like 40 images on a page, and I use `jQuery("img").load(function () {
    //run some code
});` will the code run when the first image elemnt is loaded or after the last element is loaded

Comment: With that code I think the code will be executed for each image in the webpage when they load. One image, one code execution.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm trying to work out. If it fires on the first img element then it would fire on all of them. Just not sure :/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of image use window to know if every elements of the page loaded completely.

JQUERY

```
$(window).on('load', function() { 
 // do this
});
```

or

```
$(window).load(function() { 
 // do this
});
```

Comment: Hi bella, thanks for the help. I was trying to avoid this method as sometimes a script from an external source(i.e another website) loads really slow and hangs. so the script which I want to run has to wait, which is providing a bad ux

Comment: @Web Dev Guy - hehe no worries :)